# Tip of stroke gets cut off at certain angles in inDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, path, stroke

I am lettering a comic in inDesign and I've come across this problem.

[image: Three versions of speech balloons]

When I create the speech balloons the tip of the tail is cut off. This seems to be an issue with the angle. If I keep the lines straight, there is no issue as seen in the first example from the left.

I've changed the mitre limit in the right-most tail but it goes way too far out. I have also tried to change the path alignment from middle to inside, and outside, but similar problems occur.

**My question:** Is there a way I could get a middle ground between the second and third tail?

EDIT:
I want to achieve something like this in Illustrator:
[image: Balloon tail in Illustrator]

Comment: I just copy/paste from illustrator and follow the instruction from here https://indesignsecrets.com/creating-auto-size-speech-bubbles.php I have a library with 8 different endings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to adjust the angle of the tip. The more acute it is, the longer the tail.

You don't have the same problem in the first balloon because the angle formed by the two lines connecting at the tip is much more obtuse.

To understand a bit better how miter works, check [this thread on the Adobe forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/pointy-corners-on-triangle/m-p/9551288):

The miter limit controls when the program switches from a mitered (pointed) join to a beveled (squared-off) join. A miter limit of 10 means that when the length of the point reaches ten times the stroke weight, the program switches from a miter join to a bevel join. A miter limit of 1 results in a bevel join.

See on the example below how the right join is much longer than the left, it's because of it's angle (more acute):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't really answer my question. My questions was more about how to avoid such a long tail at that angle. I don't have this problem in Illustrator, for example.

Comment: @Chris - actually this does answer the question. Luciano's suggestion to adjust the angle is the only solution that really works. Anything else would not be a true mitre join.  The [same problem occurs in Illustrator](https://imgur.com/HZIrLRG) and most vector software when the angle of a mitre is extremely small. The problem is also exacerbated when there are curves involved.

Comment: @BillyKerr So the answer to my question would be "no, there is no way to make the extremely long tail shorter."

Comment: @Chris -  Well I am sure you could edit it by expanding the strokes to paths, and altering the pointed part, but then it would then no longer be a true mitre join.  You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @Chris - here's [an example](https://imgur.com/a/11GtFor) using Luciano's suggestion to change the angle. It certainly works, and looks good too.